Calling initialize function not working
I have written a program which has deployed fine. However I am having real trouble calling the initialize function from a js script.
The code of the program is as follows:
state.rs
// src/state.rs
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey;

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct ExchangeState {
    pub total_usdc: u64,
    pub total_tokens: u64,
    pub fees_account_pubkey: Pubkey,
    pub admin_pubkey: Pubkey,
}

impl ExchangeState {
    pub const LEN: usize = 8 + 8 + 32 + 32; // 8 bytes for each u64, 32 bytes for each Pubkey
}

processor.rs
// src/processor.rs

use crate::state::ExchangeState;
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::{invoke, invoke_signed},
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    sysvar::{rent::Rent, Sysvar},
    program_pack::Pack,
};

use std::str::FromStr;
use solana_program::program_option::COption;

pub struct Processor;

impl Processor {

    // Shared constants
    pub const PRICE_PRECISION: u64 = 1_000_000_000; // Adjust as needed
    pub const USDC_MINT_ADDRESS: &'static str = "4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU"; // Replace with actual address
    pub const MINT_AUTHORITY_SEED: &'static [u8] = b"mint_authority";
    pub const USDC_AUTHORITY_SEED: &'static [u8] = b"usdc_authority";

    // Helper function to derive the mint authority PDA
    pub fn derive_mint_authority_pda(program_id: &Pubkey) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
        Pubkey::find_program_address(&[Self::MINT_AUTHORITY_SEED], program_id)
    }

    // Helper function to derive the USDC authority PDA
    pub fn derive_usdc_authority_pda(program_id: &Pubkey) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
        Pubkey::find_program_address(&[Self::USDC_AUTHORITY_SEED], program_id)
    }

    // Helper function to validate token accounts
    fn validate_token_account(
        account_info: &AccountInfo,
        expected_mint: &Pubkey,
        expected_owner: &Pubkey,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let token_account = spl_token::state::Account::unpack(&account_info.data.borrow())?;

        if token_account.mint != *expected_mint {
            msg!("Error: Token account mint does not match expected mint.");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
        }
        if token_account.owner != *expected_owner {
            msg!("Error: Token account owner does not match expected owner.");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn process(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &[AccountInfo],
        instruction_data: &[u8],
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        if instruction_data.is_empty() {
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
        }

        let instruction = instruction_data[0];
        let amount = if instruction_data.len() >= 9 {
            u64::from_le_bytes(instruction_data[1..9].try_into().unwrap())
        } else {
            0
        };

        match instruction {
            0x00 => Self::process_initialize(program_id, accounts),
            0x01 => Self::process_buy(program_id, accounts, amount),
            0x02 => Self::process_sell(program_id, accounts, amount),
            0x03 => Self::process_update_fees_account(program_id, accounts),
            _ => Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),
        }
    }

    // In process_initialize function

    fn process_initialize(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

        let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // Signer
        let token_mint = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let fees_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let admin_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // Signer
        let rent_sysvar_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let token_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

        // Ensure the admin is a signer
        if !admin_account.is_signer {
            msg!("Error: Admin account must be a signer.");
            return Err(ProgramError::MissingRequiredSignature);
        }

        // Derive the PDA for the exchange state account
        let exchange_state_seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[b"exchange_state"];
        let (exchange_state_pda, exchange_state_bump_seed) =
            Pubkey::find_program_address(exchange_state_seeds, program_id);

        // Get the exchange state account from accounts
        let exchange_state_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

        // Check that the exchange state account provided matches the PDA
        if *exchange_state_account.key != exchange_state_pda {
            msg!("Error: Invalid exchange state account provided.");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
        }

        // Create exchange state account if it doesn't exist
        let rent = &Rent::from_account_info(rent_sysvar_account)?;
        if exchange_state_account.lamports() == 0 {
            let required_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(ExchangeState::LEN);

            let create_pda_account_ix = solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
                &initializer.key,
                &exchange_state_pda,
                required_lamports,
                ExchangeState::LEN as u64,
                program_id,
            );

            let exchange_state_signer_seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[
                b"exchange_state",
                &[exchange_state_bump_seed],
            ];

            invoke_signed(
                &create_pda_account_ix,
                &[
                    initializer.clone(),
                    exchange_state_account.clone(),
                    system_program.clone(),
                ],
                &[exchange_state_signer_seeds],
            )?;
        }

        // Verify the owner of the exchange state account
        if exchange_state_account.owner != program_id {
            msg!("Error: Exchange state account is not owned by the program.");
            return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
        }

        // Initialize exchange state
        let exchange_state = ExchangeState {
            total_usdc: 0,
            total_tokens: 0,
            fees_account_pubkey: *fees_account.key,
            admin_pubkey: *admin_account.key,
        };
        exchange_state.serialize(&mut &mut exchange_state_account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;

        // Set mint authority to PDA
        let (mint_authority_pda, _mint_bump_seed) = Self::derive_mint_authority_pda(program_id);

        // Verify that the initializer is the current mint authority
        let mint_account = spl_token::state::Mint::unpack(&token_mint.data.borrow())?;
        if mint_account.mint_authority != COption::Some(*initializer.key) {
            msg!("Error: Initializer is not the current mint authority.");
            return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
        }

        let set_authority_ix = spl_token::instruction::set_authority(
            &spl_token::id(),
            &token_mint.key,
            Some(&mint_authority_pda),
            spl_token::instruction::AuthorityType::MintTokens,
            &initializer.key,
            &[],
        )?;
        invoke(
            &set_authority_ix,
            &[
                token_mint.clone(),
                initializer.clone(),
                token_program.clone(),
            ],
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

... other functions
 
}

as you will see from the code there is a function which initilizes the program and sets everything up.
I have a js script like this which is supposed to call the function.
const {
    Connection,
    clusterApiUrl,
    Keypair,
    PublicKey,
    SystemProgram,
    SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
    Transaction,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    TransactionInstruction,
} = require('@solana/web3.js');

const {
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    createSetAuthorityInstruction,
    AuthorityType,
    getMint,
    getAssociatedTokenAddress,
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    setAuthority,
} = require('@solana/spl-token'); // Correct import as per your clarification

const { serialize } = require('borsh');
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {
    try {
        // Connect to Devnet with your Helius RPC
        const connection = new Connection("https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=*****", 'confirmed');

        // Define your Program ID
        const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("Goqo65XZYGcbCpYxbPfYguokmoUFpzwDpHH51o9CcPbp"); // Replace with your actual Program ID

        // Load your wallets
        const adminKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
            Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('admin_account.json')))
        );

        const initializerKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
            Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('minting_account.json')))
        );

        const feesKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
            Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fees_account.json')))
        );


        // Use existing token mint
        const tokenMintPubkey = new PublicKey('G4FzDyTpNpN9PPPnG47vmdDPYveUekuJBHridHk2v9Hh');

        // Verify that initializer is the current mint authority
        const mintInfo = await getMint(connection, tokenMintPubkey);
        console.log('Current Mint Authority:', mintInfo.mintAuthority ? mintInfo.mintAuthority.toBase58() : 'None');

        if (mintInfo.mintAuthority.toBase58() !== initializerKeypair.publicKey.toBase58()) {
            console.log("Setting initializer as the new mint authority.");
            const setAuthorityIx = await setAuthority(
                tokenMintPubkey,
                adminKeypair, // Current authority
                AuthorityType.MintTokens,
                initializerKeypair.publicKey
            );

            const tx = new Transaction().add(setAuthorityIx);
            const setAuthSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
                connection,
                tx,
                [adminKeypair],
                { skipPreflight: false, preflightCommitment: 'confirmed' }
            );

            console.log('Set mint authority transaction signature:', setAuthSignature);
        } else {
            console.log("Initializer is already the mint authority.");
        }

        // Fees account (associated token account for feesKeypair)
        const feesAccountPubkey = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
            tokenMintPubkey,
            feesKeypair.publicKey,    // Owner of the fees account
            false,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
            ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        );

        // Check if the fees account exists
        const feesAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(feesAccountPubkey);

        let createFeesAccountIx;
        if (!feesAccountInfo) {
            // Create the fees account (associated token account)
            createFeesAccountIx = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                initializerKeypair.publicKey, // Payer
                feesAccountPubkey,
                feesKeypair.publicKey,        // Owner (fees account owner)
                tokenMintPubkey,
                TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
                ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            );
            console.log("Fees account does not exist. It will be created.");
        } else {
            console.log("Fees account already exists.");
        }

        // Derive the exchange state PDA
        const EXCHANGE_STATE_SEED = 'exchange_state';
        const exchangeStateSeed = Buffer.from(EXCHANGE_STATE_SEED);
        const [exchangeStatePDA, exchangeStateBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [exchangeStateSeed],
            PROGRAM_ID // Your actual Program ID
        );

        console.log("Exchange State PDA:", exchangeStatePDA.toBase58());


        // Prepare the initialize instruction
        const instructionData = Buffer.from([0x00]); // Initialize instruction

        const keys = [
            { pubkey: initializerKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }, // Signer
            { pubkey: tokenMintPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },             // Token Mint
            { pubkey: feesAccountPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },          // Fees Account
            { pubkey: adminKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },      // Admin (Signer)
            { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
            { pubkey: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },      // Token Program ID
            { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
            // { pubkey: exchangeStatePDA, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },            // Exchange State PDA
        ];

        const initializeInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
            programId: PROGRAM_ID, // Your actual Program ID
            keys,
            data: instructionData,
        });

        // Create a transaction
        const transaction = new Transaction();

        if (createFeesAccountIx) {
            transaction.add(createFeesAccountIx);
        }

        // Add the initializeInstruction
        transaction.add(initializeInstruction);

        // Prepare the list of signers
        const signers = [initializerKeypair, adminKeypair];

        // Send the transaction
        const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            connection,
            transaction,
            signers,
            { skipPreflight: false, preflightCommitment: 'confirmed' }
        );

        console.log('Initialization transaction signature:', signature);

        // Optionally, print account information for verification
        const exchangeStateAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(exchangeStatePDA);
        console.log("Exchange State PDA Exists:", !!exchangeStateAccount);
        console.log("Exchange State PDA Owner:", exchangeStateAccount?.owner.toBase58());

        const feesAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(feesAccountPubkey);
        console.log("Fees Account Exists:", !!feesAccount);
        console.log("Fees Account Owner:", feesAccount?.owner.toBase58());
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.logs) {
            console.error("Transaction Logs:", error.logs);
        }
        console.error("Error during initialization:", error);
    }
})();

However when I run it the console produces this output.
Error during initialization: TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError

Solana is kind of new to me and the complexities of the accounts are hard to follow so not sure really where I am going wrong with this one. Any help appreciated.

Maybe you can share more output from the program? Having seen what console.log and in case if some transaction log errors are printed could be helpful to understand the error.
